# Invalid Cross Reference ID when importing Tasks

Tags: data-loader

I'm trying to import TASKS related to opportunities from one Salesforce org to another using Data Loader.
I have done Excel VLookkups on all Id Values, and all related objects/records are in place on the target org.  So, the import CSV includes opportunityId, AccountId, OwnerId from the target org.

I'm getting an error for all records-  'invalid cross reference id'.
I'd like to know which of the related objects does DataLoader use to match records, or what other issue might be behind this error.

Thank you!

Comment: The CSV should not include the AccountId as SFDC will set that automatically from the Task.WhatId (Opportunity) => AccountId. That is, the Task.AccountId will be the Oppo's AccountId

Answer (score 0):

Are your accounts and opportunities already linked before you upload task records? If not, then maybe below applies?

[image: Task]

Comment: I'm still checking this, but I would like to know where you found this documentation so I can get up to speed on this.   Thanks for taking time.

Comment: I got this here [link] https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_task.htm

Comment: Thank you Gxian Drive-  helps if you read the documentation.